# converting asp.net to asp.net core issue on onredirecttoidentityprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

recently we have migrated our project from asp.net to asp.net core, the project was working fine in asp.net, We have followed the migration document of Microsoft for migrating "asp.net to asp.net core" and modified accordingly, unfortunately, OnRedirectToIdentityProvider method in startup class is not working on challenge call (from the controller). It would be great if someone helps me to figure out where my code is wrong. I have been looping on the same issue for a while. thanks in advance.

**StartUp.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
         {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            //Add a strongly-typed options class to DI
            services.Configure<AuthOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));



            services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddCookie("MiddleWareCookie")
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {

                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                options.ClientId= Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret= Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"];



                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in
                    // line of business apps), we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false,

                    // If the app is meant to be accessed by entire organizations, add your issuer validation logic here.
                    //IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) => {
                    //    if (myIssuerValidationLogic(issuer)) return issuer;
                    //}
                };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {

                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        object obj = null;
                        var request = context.Request;

                        if (context.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("Authority", out obj))
                        {
                            string authority = obj as string;
                            if (authority != null)
                            {
                                context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = authority;
                            }
                        }
                        //string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        string appBaseUrl = @"https://localhost:44359/";//UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase);
                        Debug.WriteLine($"appBaseUrl: {appBaseUrl}");
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Resource =  Configuration["Authentication:AzureResourceManagerIdentifier"];
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
                        var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                        var credential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);
                        string tenantId = context.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

                        //Comment
                        Debug.WriteLine($"tenantID: {tenantId}");
                        // Revisit
                        string signedInUserUniqueName = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value.Split('#')[context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value.Split('#').Length - 1];
                        //Comment
                        Debug.WriteLine($"tenantID: {signedInUserUniqueName}");

                        var tokenCache = new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserUniqueName);
                        tokenCache.Clear();

                        // revisit
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantId), tokenCache);
                        // var items = authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().ToList();

                        // revisit
                        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                             context.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential);

                        //Tell the OIDC middleware we got the tokens, it doesn't need to do anything
                        context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);

                    },

                    OnTokenValidated = (context) => {
                           string issuer = context.Principal.FindFirst("iss").Value;
                        if (issuer != null)
                        {
                            if (!issuer.StartsWith("https://sts.windows.net/"))
                                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
                        }


                        return Task.FromResult(0);

                    },

                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // If your authentication logic is based on users then add your logic here
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    // If your application needs to do authenticate single users, add your user validation below.
                    //OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    //{
                    //    return myUserValidationLogic(context.Ticket.Principal);
                    //}
                };
            });

            services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Subscription Controller Method**

```
HttpContext.Items.Add("Authority", string.Format(_authOptions.Authority + "OAuth2/Authorize", _directoryId));

                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dict["prompt"] = "select_account";

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Claims, "login");

                ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("MiddleWareCookie");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things that explain why `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` is not called based on your controller code:

- you're calling the `AuthenticateAsync` method where your question states you're calling `Challenge`;
- you're referring to the cookie authentication scheme (`MiddleWareCookie`), where I think your intent is to trigger an OpenID Connect login.

I believe you need to replace `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("MiddleWareCookie")` with `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync()` to have the OIDC login request be triggered.

Another potential issue I can see is that you set, in the `AddAuthentication` method, the `DefaultScheme` to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, but the name of your cookie authentication scheme is `MiddleWareCookie`. These two need to be in sync.

Comment: thanks for the response, let me try and keep you posted on the same.